# Handling divs in CSS-3

Tags: html, css

how can we move div on a webpage at any position, what is an accurate CSS property for overcoming or handling this problem? I can't set the position of multiple divs at different places on a web page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Muhammad, could you please provide us with some HTML and CSS you have to reference while we try to assist you with your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: relative;` on the parent element and `position: absolute;` together with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` CSS properties on the children. Or you can use `position: fixed` on the element with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` CSS properties. Example

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 100px;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;background: red;"></div>
  <div>Sit adipisicing et deserunt laborum consectetur tempor proident eu duis ex ut id eu deserunt occaecat excepteur veniam ea laborum esse velit consectetur cillum et nulla non cillum magna aute esse velit dolor esse mollit dolor anim duis dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @ruleboy21's answer -
Let's say div A is the element you want to freely control.

Now if you want to control div A anywhere inside another parent element, you use `position: relative` on the parent element and use `position: absolute` on div A and control it using left, right, top and bottom.

If you want to control the div inside the viewport of the webpage, so it is independent of other divs regardless of where it exists in the DOM hierarchy, you use `position: fixed` and control it with left, right, top and bottom.